# lxc-create says container already exists

Tags: lxc

I'm trying to create a container on a non-standard location, but lxc-create complains the roots already exists, when, in fact, it seems it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
leon@ln00:/media/leon/Archive/lxc$ sudo lxc-ls
saucy-amd64-chromiumos  

leon@ln00:/media/leon/Archive/lxc$ sudo lxc-destroy -n saucy-amd64-chromiumos

leon@ln00:/media/leon/Archive/lxc$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 leon leon 4096 Nov 24 22:03 ./
drwx------ 4 leon leon 4096 Nov 24 21:49 ../

leon@ln00:/media/leon/Archive/lxc$ time sudo lxc-create -n saucy-amd64-chromiumos -t ubuntu -B dir --dir /media/leon/Archive/lxc/ -- -r saucy

lxc-create: No config file specified, using the default config /etc/lxc/default.conf
specified rootfs (/media/leon/Archive/lxc/) already exists.  Bailing.

real    0m0.029s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.008s

leon@ln00:/media/leon/Archive/lxc$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 leon leon 4096 Nov 24 22:03 ./
drwx------ 4 leon leon 4096 Nov 24 21:49 ../

leon@ln00:/media/leon/Archive/lxc$ sudo ls -al /var/cache/lxc/
total 8
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Out 29 16:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Nov 24 21:53 ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-B dir --dir is used to specify the rootfs path of the container. That should point to a non-existing path in which to put the rootfs. If that's really what you want, just destroy the directory and LXC should be happy (the container's config and fstab will be created under /var/lib/lxc/ but the rootfs will be /media/leon/Archive/lxc/).

If you instead simply want to use an alternate location for your containers (instead of the standard /var/lib/lxc). To do that, use the --lxcpath|-P option instead.

`sudo lxc-create -n saucy-amd64-chromiumos -t ubuntu -P /media/leon/Archive/lxc/ -- -r saucy`

This parameter is accepted by most lxc commands, so you'll also be able to do:

`lxc-ls -P /media/leon/Archive/lxc/`

And pass it to lxc-start/lxc-stop/...

You may also make this permanent by setting "lxcpath = /media/leon/Archive/lxc/" in /etc/lxc/lxc.conf (you'll have to create this file, it doesn't exist by default).

All the above assumes a pretty recent version of LXC (one of the 1.0 pre-releases).